# Populate XML tag more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xsd

The task i have is to create XML from XSD given.

I have made use of xsd.exe to generate a class with a bunch of properties in it.

One of the property is of return type array of class.

ex :

```
public class BrokerConfirmation
{
    public BrokerConfirmation();
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public string SchemaVersion { get; set; }
    public string SellerParty { get; set; }
    public string SenderID { get; set; }
    public BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity[] TimeIntervalQuantities { get; set; } 
}
```

BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity class is as follows

```
public class BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity
{
    public BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity();

    public decimal ContractCapacity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryEndDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryStartDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool PriceSpecified { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to display the TAGS of BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity class more than once .

How can i achieve it ?

The code i have tried to populate time interval qty only once is as follows :

```
var data = new BrokerConfirmation();
XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
data.TimeIntervalQuantities = new BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity[]
                {
                   new BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity {
                      DeliveryStartDateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-10-01"),
                      DeliveryEndDateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-10-30"),
                      ContractCapacity = trade.Quantity,
                      Price = trade.Price,
                      PriceSpecified = true};

                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm,

```
var data = new BrokerConfirmation();
XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
data.TimeIntervalQuantities = new BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity[]
            {
               new BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity {...}, 
               // More instances here....
               new BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity {...}, 
               new BrokerConfirmationTimeIntervalQuantity {...},
               // etc...
            };
```

Comment: Thanks hugh. it was helpful answer. Instead i tried it using foreach loop.